# postgresql function that inserts and validates

Tags: postgresql, function, if-statement, insert

I'm trying to make a function that inserts a new person from a table and validates the gender of the person (must be 'male' or 'female'). I know how to make a function that inserts a new person and I know how to make a function that raises an exception if the gender is now male or female. But I don't know how to do this in one function and without using a trigger.

What I have already is something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION InsertPerson(IN _id INTEGER, IN _name VARCHAR(50), IN _gender CHAR(1))
RETURNS void
AS 
$$

  BEGIN

    IF NEW.gender <> 'Female' AND NEW.gender <> 'Male' THEN
       RAISE EXCEPTION 'Gender must be either Female or Male';
    END IF;


    INSERT INTO Person (ID, name, gender)
    VALUES(_id, _name, _gender);


  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Can someone please help me

Comment: have you considered an enum column instead of varchar. This will automatically only allow the values you have specified. This will probably also make your database quicker for searching and referencing, because searching/matching string/char is relatively slow

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do the check in a function. What if somebody inserts directly into the table bypassing the function? A check constraint would be better.

```
ALTER TABLE person
            ADD CHECK (gender IN ('Female', 'Male'));
```

If you insist on the function just check `_gender` (which should be longer than one character if it can hold `Female` or `Male`) instead `new.gender`.

```
...
IF _gender <> 'Female'
   AND _gender <> 'Male' THEN
  RAISE EXCEPTION 'Gender must be either Female or Male';
END IF;
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I understand that check would be better, but I just want to see if I can make it work using only a function. I changed the function according to your suggestion and while it works to create the function, when I insert something other then male or female I don't get the raise exception message: 'Gender must be either Female or Male' that I wanted. (I've changed the _gender so it has more then 1 char now) ..

Comment: @shiverrose: Works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=819a50bad27c87b92817ef8845ff596e

Comment: aah okey, when I do it like this: SELECT InsertPerson(2, 'baz', 'Wrong'); it works. But not if I insert it like this: INSERT INTO Person(ID, name, gender)  VALUES (2, 'baz', 'Wrong'); Then it just inserts the data.

Comment: @shiverrose: Of course it does if you just `INSERT`. You're bypassing the function if you do just an `INSERT`. That's exactly what I meant when I recommended the `CHECK` constraint.